# Git: How to merge local branch with remote tracking automatically without fetching

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-branch

Imagine, I have several branches: master, a, b, c ...

Now I'm in master branch and "git pull". This fetches all changes from remote server into origin/master, origin/a, origin/b ... branches and merges CURRENT branch (master) with origin/master. But then I want to switch to A branch and again merge these remote changes from remote tracked branch, WITHOUT fetching changes again (as they already are in origin/a branch).

Is there some simplier way to do this not specifying exactly remote branch I track (i.e. automatically) ?

Comment: I am fairly certain the OP wants to avoid having to explicitly name the remote branch, as is possible with `git pull` - git knows what branch to fetch and merge. That is, `git merge origin/a` is not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a built-in command for this. However, you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
head=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD) || exit
head=${head#refs/heads/}
merge=$(git config --get branch.$head.merge) || { echo "no tracking branch"; exit 1; }
remote=$(git config --get branch.$head.remote) || remote=origin
git merge $remote/${merge#refs/heads/}

# alternatively, as in Aristotle's answer:
# head=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD) || exit
# upstream=$(git for-each-ref --format='%(upstream:short)' "$head"
# [ -z "$upstream" ] && { echo "no tracking branch"; exit 1; }
# git merge $upstream
```

I think I've covered my bases pretty well - it exits with failure status if in detached HEAD state, or if the current branch doesn't have a tracking branch. It defaults the to origin, as do the normal git transfer commands. (Something weird will happen if you try to use it on a branch which is tracking something other than a branch on the remote, i.e. not of the form refs/heads/*, but that seems pretty unlikely.) Doesn't seem like it'd actually save you much time, but there you are!

If you want to use it, just store it somewhere and alias to it, or name it git-something and put it in your PATH.

Comment: @Zebooka: For what it's worth, this feature was just added. [Commit 93e535a](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=93e535a5b78c9861eca3e9371d1c3e5173c0ab02) allows you to set a config option `merge.defaultupstream` which will cause `git merge` (with no arguments) to merge with the appropriate remote tracking branch - just like a `git pull` without the fetch. My guess would be that it might make it into v1.7.5.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply checkout your local branch and merge from your local copy of the origin/a branch.

Something like:

```
git checkout a
git merge origin/a
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is no answer at all - see my comment on the question. Don't want to downvote though, as I could be wrong.

Comment: Well to me it seems he just doesn't want to reach the server again. He states "WITHOUT fetching changes again (as they already are in origin/a branch)." So the part he doesn't want to do is fetching. Although I may have understood it wrong as well. Best leave it to the OP to decide or give more details. :)

Answer (score 0):

`git pull` is nothing more than `git fetch` + `git merge`. With the parameter `--rebase` you can also have it rebase and not merge so you can just switch to the other branch and merge/rebase:

```
git checkout a
git merge origin/a
```

or:

```
git checkout a
git rebase a
```

Since it doesn't do anything else I even have stopped using pull at all. I just `git fetch` regularly so I can track the changes in other repositories easily and then `git merge/rebase` whenever I'm ready.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is no answer at all - see my comment on the question. Don't want to downvote though, as I could be wrong.

Comment: Yeah this is a no answer. It's not clear how this applys to the OP situation and the introduction to the answer talks about --rebase, bot doesn't really explain the following examples.  Badly written answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will check out all tracking branches in turn, and merge in their corresponding remote branches:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short) %(upstream:short)' \
| while read branch upstream ; do
    [ -z "$upstream" ] && continue
    git checkout "$branch"
    git merge "$upstream" || git reset --hard
done
```

If a merge has conflicts, it is rewound with `git reset` and you will have to do it manually.

Untested.

You can also pass one or more patterns to `git for-each-ref` to restrict it to a certain branch or a certain set of them.

Comment: This is dangerous. If `git merge` refuses to try to merge, because the work tree has modifications, the `reset --hard` will destroy those modifications. `reset --merge` would be safer, but still not totally safe. (And I know you have a checkout there, but with local modifications, it'd either have failed or left them in place while switching branches - either way, there are still local modifications.)

Comment: Dangerous, but seems to be a hint how to make auto update current branch. Thanks